# Query to find results starting with a number or higher - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7f3df/2

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
Reg uniqueidentifier
);

INSERT INTO Table1 (Reg)
Values
('DF215E10-8BD4-4401-B2DC-99BB03135F2E'),
('93015E10-8BD4-4401-B2DC-99BB03135F2E'),
('21215E10-8BD4-4401-B2DC-99BB03135F2E');
```

Query:

```
select * from Table1
WHERE left(CAST(Reg AS CHAR(36)),1) > 8
```

I need to create a query that finds all results that start with either a number 8 or higher or starts with a letter but i am getting a conversion error i cant find a fix for. The column is a uniqueidentifier. How can i cast this to something i can filter on?

Can anyone give some advice on a solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use SQL Server's enhanced `LIKE` here, which has some basic regex support:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE Reg LIKE '[89A-Z]%';
```

The pattern `[89A-Z]%` says to match a starting 8 or 9, or any letter.

Answer (score 8):

You need to do the comparison using strings:

```
convert(varchar(36), newid()) like '[89ABCDEF]%'
```

Comment: Believe it or not, the cast [appears to not be necessary](https://rextester.com/XVJCH98903).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . True.  I just try to be very careful about using implicit conversion.